# Generate thumbnail for preview of a url ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, url, preview

I need to create a preview of the url with the thumbnail and some metadata with. How can i get the thumbnail of the url and metadata so that i generate a preview of the url.
I have no idea how get thumbnail and metadata.I've searched for this, but could not get anything in iOS(not in objective or swift). I will be thankful for any useful links as well.

Comment: There is no easy way to get a preview thumbnail of an arbitrary webpage.  You'll have to load it in a web view and generate the thumbnail yourself.  If you only need previews for some small set of webpages that you control, generate them on the server and download them from a well known location.

Comment: The webpage will always be arbitrary. If i load the url in webview, how can i access the metadata for that page?

Comment: You mean this? https://github.com/marty-suzuki/URLEmbeddedView

Comment: URL does not have any metadata. You have to download the data from URL. Loading on web view is useless. Ultimately web view will also download the data from URL. Do it yourself and get whatever you want (thumbnail and metadata in your case).

Comment: @iOS_devloper  Thanks for the useful link. I'll have a look at it

Comment: @Darshana i am getting few issues while integrating as you mentioned  framework, have you tried this earlier, if so was it worked?

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper yes it was working previously with swift 2.0, but not with swift 3.0 so i used this as alternative https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/SwiftLinkPreview

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper Yes, i used it  and working fine with Swift 2.0. You can check alternative as suggested by Arun here.

Comment: @Darshana, i need some help on this, can you?

Comment: @ArunK any idea about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44301971/how-to-integrate-both-objective-c-and-swift-pods-in-same-project-in-ios-app

Comment: @Darshana any idea about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44301971/how-to-integrate-both-objective-c-and-swift-pods-in-same-project-in-ios-app

Answer (score 2):

You can use a preview i dont know if this is what you are expecting. In this example im downloading the preview of the metadata site. Then I have a UIView and adding in the MAIN THREAD with:

self?.viewContainer.addSubview(linkPreview)

I hope this will help you!

Your friendly Mexican neighbor  R.A, Regards

```
import LinkPresentation

func fetchPreview(urlString: String){
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return
        }
        let linkPreview = LPLinkView()
        let provider = LPMetadataProvider()
        provider.startFetchingMetadata(for: url, completionHandler: {
            [weak self] metaData, error in
            guard let data = metaData, error == nil else{
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                linkPreview.metadata = data
                self?.viewContainer.addSubview(linkPreview)
                linkPreview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 349, height: 245)
            }
            
        })
    }
```

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvtJZ.png)