# How to integrate both Objective-C and Swift pods in same project in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

I am doing Objective-C in iOS app. But the problem is I want to add few Objective-C apis into that I added successfully earlier with cocoa pods, But, now I want to add Swift Api through cocoa pods, but the problem getting while installing is following.

[!] Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it. The Swift Pods being used are: apis

But I can't add this manually due to its large api and it contains sub folders.

But, if I remove "#" key from use_frameworks!, its getting installed, but, the old Objective-C apis getting file not found in my project.
Even I have very basic knowledge at installing frameworks/apis through cocoa pods.

Can any one suggest me how to over come this.

Answer (score 1):

`use_frameworks!` will work with `Objective-C` pod only if they are dynamic frameworks not static libraries. Most of the popular third party libraries are using dynamic frameworks like `AFNetworking`, `GoogleMaps` etc.

Make sure all your `Objective-C` pods are dynamic frameworks. If you are not sure just create a sample project with `cocoapods` and use `use_frameworks!`. Try adding one by one, all the pods and find out which one is the culprit.

Comment: after I did it, its showing existing framework which was installed in Objective-C in pods, while compiling the app, showing ld: library not found for -apiname clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: if anyone of your `Objective-C` pod is static library and is not available in dynamic framework then Im afraid you can't use `use_framework!`

Comment: Its existing project I am working on it, and that Objective-C api, I am not able to add it as manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem once, what I did was use `use_frameworks!` like you mentioned, and then I changed how the Objective-C `imports` are written.

The command `use_frameworks!` turns each pod into a Framework, so in your projects the .h and .m files are no longer visible to the `import` like they would usually.

As a result, instead of using for example `#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>`, you do `@import AFNetworking;`

From my own experience, and maybe it was just a special case for my project. But turning everything into frameworks slowed down the compile time on Xcode and it made my App Package bigger for some reason.

Comment: after I did it, its showing existing framework which was installed in Objective-C in pods, while compiling the app, showing ld: library not found for -apiname
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Podfile file:

```
 platform :ios, '10.0'
    use_frameworks!

    def pods
        pod 'Alamofire', '= 4.4'
        pod 'SwiftyJSON' '= 3.1.4'
        pod 'MBProgressHUD'
    end

    target 'YourProject' do
        pods
    end
```

YourProject-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import <MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.h>
```

Build Settings
[image]

Comment: did you understand whats the question first?

Comment: I have already Objective-C apis in pod file, now I want to install Swift api in same pod, thats the question.